# How To make Custom page of every Category

Tags: customization, page-template, templates

Hii i have seen many blogs which posted thing in the same design for example 
if you see this
http://www.songs-pk.info/2011/nayika-malayalam-2011/

there page create alwayz in the same style download button and play button and the same td tr combination
how can i make this
mean did we just have to give links once we create page ?
or how this all is possible for maximum time saving

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? As written, it is incredibly difficult to understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `category-<slug>.php` or `category-<ID>.php` in your theme. 
e.g. category-jazz.php to view songs categorized in jazz category and category-rock.php to view songs categorized in rock category.

PS>*This answer is based upon your title. I couldn't understand what you have written in the question.*